# React Typescript: Passing a type on a react component call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prettier

What is the proper way to pass a type into a component call?

In this example, The render prop APICall takes in a type parameter called MobileSplashReturn. Technically, this example works, but it is breaking prettier, which leads me to believe that this is not a best practice.

```
 <APICall<MobileSplashReturn> endpoint="apps/mobile_splash">
        {({data, error, loading, refetch}) => {
          console.log('data: ', data);
          return (
            <ThisView>
              <Text>Login Screen</Text>
             </ThisView>
          )}}
      </APICall>
```

Comment: This does not look like a valid JSX syntax to me. Are you sure it works?

Comment: Yes, it works just fine. If this does not look like valid JSX syntax, how would you recommend passing in a generic type into the component?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to an old version of prettier. I had an older version of prettier installed as a dev dependency. I upgraded it to 1.17.1, reloaded the window, and it formatted just fine.